# Bash Echo String $"$value" versus "$value" versus in method $"${@}"

Tags: string, bash, printing, echo

To be specific, I'm using

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I'm reading some old bash code and there are a lot of inconsistencies with how strings are displayed and passed around.

I understand that echoing a string with newline characters without surrounding quotes will be handled by bash:

```
newstr="Some
        Dummy
        String"

echo ${newstr}
echo "${newstr}"

# Returns
Some Dummy String
Some
        Dummy
        String
```

What are the differences between the following methods of echoing displaying strings?

```
#!/bin/bash

mystr="Some Generic String"

echo $mystr
echo ${mystr}

echo "$mystr"
echo "${mystr}"

echo $"$mystr"
echo $"${mystr}"

jobSecurityEcho()
{
    echo $"$@"
}
jobSecurityEcho $mystr
jobSecurityEcho ${mystr}
jobSecurityEcho "$mystr"
jobSecurityEcho "${mystr}"
jobSecurityEcho $"$mystr"
jobSecurityEcho $"${mystr}"
jobSecurityEcho $(jobSecurityEcho ${mystr})
```

Other than the newlines being interpreted when echo'd without quotes, are all of the above equivalent? When I run this script, I get "Some Generic String" printed out thirteen times. Is there a reason to do one way over another? Can I simplify this to simply use `echo ${mystr}` and `echo "${mystr}"` respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to be more about variable substitution than about strings. Note that in contrast to other programming languages, Bash does not require strings to be quoted. Quotes and double quotes are used to affect tokenization, substitution and expansion.

There are two best practices to remember for variable substitution:

- Variable substitutions should (almost) always be double-quoted:

  ```
  "$VARIABLE"
  ```

  This makes sure Bash treats the content as one token even if there are whitespace characters in the variable's value. An example where you would *not* double-quote the variable would be if it contained tokens you want to loop through.
- Variable substitutions inside double-quoted strings that contain more than just the variable should be enclosed in curly braces:

  ```
  "${VARIABLE}something/else"
  ```

Last but not least, the special syntax `$"..."` causes the double-quoted part to be translated. As `bash(1)` states:

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will
>   cause the string to be translated according to the current locale. If
>   the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the
>   string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.